# Extract files from a .exe file

Tags: macos, terminal

on Windows we can extract files from an .exe file pretty easily but I couldn't find any terminal command to do similar things. I imagine this is because some .exe are compressed in such way OS X cannot interpret. Did anyone find a way to do it? I can of course do it easily through a VM or on a Windows OS, but I like to know if there is an quick method that I am just not aware of.

Okay, I think I need to note this is not for compressed zip files that has an extension of exe.

Comment: Not al exe are compressed files so not all can have files extracted from them - perhaps yours are zipped then try The Unarchiver from the app store

Answer (score 1):

Try the Keka program. It's free and on the website says it can extract EXEs 
[Keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/)